# Python, модуль pynput и keyboard, не работает ввод с клавиатуры

Tags: python-3.x, python-keyboard, pynput

В VSCode при запуске ячейки с кодом не происходит ввод текста, вместо этого появляются новые ячейки сдвигая код вниз

```
import keyboard
keyboard.write("Hello")
```

[image: выполнение кода]

При запуске этого кода:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

      keyboard = Controller()

      keyboard.type('Hello World')
```

Так же не происходит ввода. В чем может быть причина?